# Cordova build issue in ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

I was following the tutorials @ http://www.gaggl.com/2014/04/apache-cordova-development-environment-install-on-ubuntu/

Cordova build is failing with message:

:~/projects/Hello$ sudo cordova build

```
Running command: /home/skn/projects/Hello/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/skn/projects/Hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/skn/projects/Hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

I have included the android in the path variable also.

```
skn@bangre:~/projects/Hello$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/bin/java:/usr/bin/ant:.:/home/skn/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/skn/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

From screenshot below you can see the sdk is installed 
[image]

Also I have the following check which is passing.

```
skn@bangre:~/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.7.1/package/bin$ ./android_sdk_version 
 21

skn@bangre:~/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.7.1/package/bin$ ./check_reqs 
Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!
```

Please help me point out the issue.

Comment: Did you find answer on your question?

Comment: yes turns out the cordova node.js scripts assumes the android sdk directory name as 'android-sdk' , for ubuntu when we unzip we get 'android-linux-sdk'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes turns out the cordova node.js scripts assumes the android sdk directory name as 'android-sdk' , for ubuntu when we unzip we get 'android-linux-sdk'